# Why would Nginx 1.14.2 show version 1.10.3 in error messages

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx 1.14.2 on ubuntu 16.  I'm having trouble figuring out a 413 error (which I'll address separately), but I noticed that when I post a file to the nginx server, it reports, presumably, the error message and the version of nginx:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
```

The command nginx -v shows the version to be 1.14.2.  I checked the startup files to see if maybe they were pointing to some other version, but they all point to /usr/sbin/nginx which is what is telling me the version is 1.14.2.

So why does it say 1.10.3 in the error message?

I need to rule out this discrepancy as the cause of my other problem.

Comment: Where did you get nginx 1.14.2? How did it get onto your system?

Comment: I got nginx 1.14.2 by following these instructions:  https://www.tecklyfe.com/how-to-upgrade-nginx-to-latest-stable-version-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Those directions seem reasonable. But did you actually do the last one: restart nginx?

Comment: At this point I've restarted it many times trying different combinations of configuration parameters in pursuit of fixing the 413 error.  I should have mentioned that before I upgraded, nginx -v indicated I had 1.14.1.  It should have never been 1.10.3.

Comment: Have you tried to stop nginx and check that it really stopped?

Comment: I powered the VM down and then back on again, which should have made sure it really stopped.

Comment: Does your nginx have an `error_page 413` in its configuration? Is this the only nginx that you have running, or is it possibly a reverse proxy in front of another nginx?